# Why does Scapy cause network to stop working?

Tags: python, scapy

When performing a scan of my primary interface's network, I notice that the SSH console stops responding until the scan is over.

Lets use this example:

```
import scapy.all as scapy

scapy.arping("10.0.0.0/24")
```

While this is running, I have a continuous ping running in the background, and that stops until the python script is finished.

If I perform this same test on another interface that is not the primary interface, such as a secondary network: `192.168.1.0/24` then I do not have this problem.

1. Can someone explain why this happens?
2. How can this be avoided?

Comment: I've found the threshold is a /26. When doing this test with a /27 or higher, there is no perceptible lag in the SSH terminal.